# sending html email from APEX using templates

Tags: apex, email, email-template, apex-email-service, singleemailmessage

When I am doing a test send using the data in the quote object record, I am getting an html formatted email with values.

In the doc: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_classes_email_outbound_single.htm

It says:

`setTargetObjectId(targetObjectId)` Required if using a template, optional otherwise. The `ID` of the contact, lead, or user to which the email will be sent. The `ID` you specify sets the context and ensures that merge fields in the template contain the correct data.

`setWhatId(whatId)` If you specify a contact for the `targetObjectId` field, you can specify an optional `whatId` as well. This helps to further ensure that merge fields in the template contain the correct data.

Not sure what values should be set for these:

```
mail.setTargetObjectId(); 

mail.setWhatId();
```

Merge fields in my classic email template are like: `{!Quote.Opportunity_Amount__c}`

I am not sure I the SELECT should be like instead:

```
EmailTemplate et = [SELECT Id, Subject, Description, HtmlValue, DeveloperName, Body FROM EmailTemplate WHERE Name = 'My template name'];
```

Following is the code snippet I am using:

```
for (Quote q: Qt){
     EmailTemplate et = [SELECT Id, Subject, Body FROM EmailTemplate WHERE DeveloperName =:emailTemplateName];
                List<string> toAddress = new List<string>();
                toAddress.add(q.Customer_Email__c);
                Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
                    mail.setTemplateId(et.Id);
                    mail.setToAddresses(toAddress);
                    mail.setSubject(et.subject);
                    mail.setHTMLBody(et.Body);
                    mail.setTargetObjectId();
                    mail.setWhatId();
                    mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);
                    mail.setUseSignature(false);
                List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> allmsg = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
                allmsg.add(mail);

                try {
                    Messaging.sendEmail(allmsg,false);
                    return;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.debug(e.getMessage());
                }
}
```

Comment: By setting the template ID this automatically identifies the subject and body to use. Simply do not set those values and allow Salesforce to sort those out for you. The who ID is the ID of the recipient record - always use this instead of to email address if possible since email address sending always uses limits- and the what ID is there to let you substitute values into the email template.

Comment: Right. I updated the code with mail.setTargetObjectId(q.Id); and removed whatid. But email doesn't seem to get sent out. Checked logs, recipient email is there... subject, etc is there... tried with two email ids...

Comment: Deliverability is set to All Emails. Also tested the deliverability and received 16 test emails.
No errors exceptions in the logs.

Comment: I then went ahead and used Messaging.sendEmail(allmsg); instead of Messaging.sendEmail(allmsg,false);

Then I am getting the error:

QuoteTrigger: execution of AfterUpdate caused by: System.EmailException: SendEmail failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_TYPE_FOR_OPERATION, Only User, Contact, Lead, or Person objects are allowed for targetObjectId: 0Q05D0000007n08.: [targetObjectId, 0Q05D0000007n08SAA] Class.Quote_Lcs.sendemailtemplate: line 81, column 1 Trigger.QuoteTrigger: line 42, column 1

Comment: The "who ID" is the "target ID"; the recipient must be the ID of a record of one of the types of object listed. In your case, the user to which the email is to be sent. The "what ID" is the ID of a record from which you want to substitute values into the email using the relevant mailmerge markup. In your case, the quote.

Comment: My record is from Quote Object. So I gave mail.setTargetObjectId(q.Id); Does this mean, I cannot send an html email using templates from apex, for any objects other than User, Contact, Lead, or Person objects?

Comment: The target is the recipient - the person to receive the email. A quote is not a person. Where you want to include details from the quote in the email, set the quote's ID as the what ID.

Comment: Ok, so I set mail.setTargetObjectId(q.AccountId); and mail.setWhatId(q.Id);
Still getting the INVALID_TYPE_FOR_OPERATION error.
The account Object I am using is a Person Account, instead of a Business account. Is that going to be a problem?

Comment: Clearly it is. Follow the constraints defined in the documentation and find a user, contact, lead or person ID to pass as the target ID.

Comment: It worked! Received the email. Changed to the following:

mail.setTargetObjectId(q.ContactId);
mail.setWhatId(q.Id);

But now the problem is I cant get the merge field values in the email also is not received as html as per the template. It just outputs like:

Amount {!Quote.Amount__c} Discount % {!Quote.Discount__c}

Its supposed to be output in a table format...

Comment: Did you remove the setting of the subject and body, just setting the template ID?

Comment: No. Only updated these to: mail.setTargetObjectId(q.ContactId); and mail.setWhatId(q.Id); Subject of the email is retrieved from the template and displayed properly in the email received. These are the values now: mail.setTemplateId(et.Id); mail.setToAddresses(toAddress); mail.setSubject(et.subject); mail.setHTMLBody(et.Body); mail.setTargetObjectId(q.ContactId); mail.setWhatId(q.Id);

Comment: Don't set the body and subject; these should be automatically retrieved and processed by simply passing the template ID.

Comment: No, not at all. I am not setting the body and subject. Its being retrieved from the template: mail.setSubject(et.subject); mail.setHTMLBody(et.Body); Subject is displaying fine, but body not doing the mail merge just echoing the expression and the mail is not in html either.

Comment: Read what I said: **DO NOT SET THE BODY AND SUBJECT**. By setting the template ID you are telling Salesforce to go query the template body and subject for itself, and to apply mailmerge handling all in one go. If you are going to query them yourself you a) must call the required API to handle the mailmerge processing and b) should not set the template ID.

Comment: Oh man!!! removed those two lines and it worked like a charm! I will definitely remember this lesson! Thanks a bunch for following and helping me through! Appreciate it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using an email template, want to send an email using that template (and can afford for Salesforce to perform a query to load that template) and have mailmerge in the template, the easiest way to achieve this is to:

1. Call `setTemplateId` with the ID of the required email template. Do **not** separately call `setSubject`, `setHTMLBody` or `setPlainTextBody`; the template will be automatically queried for you and mailmerge will be processed for you. This mailmerge processing won't happen if you set subject/body explicitly.
2. Call `setTargetObjectId` passing in the ID of the recipient. Note that this must be a User, Contact, Lead or Person record ID. Also note that if it is not a User or Lead ID then the email send counts against your daily email sending limit.
3. Call `setWhatId` passing in the ID of the record referenced in the template's mailmerge.

If at all possible, always try to map a Contact ID to a User ID (in case you have Community Users) before using as the recipient of the email; that way you don't eat into your email daily limits.